# text is not vertically aligned in the middle of div

Tags: html, css

For some reason, attribute `vertical-align: middle;` is not applied to span tag. Here is the code:

```html
<div style="position: relative; background-color: gray; padding: 1%; width: 100%; height: 60px;">
  <div style="background-color: green; width: 50%; height: 100%">
    <span style="position: absolute; display: inline-block; text-align: center; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle">
      50%
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know the height of the element? or does the height dynamically change?

Comment: Inner div height needs to depend on outer, as you can see. So that means that I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the height of the outer div is 60px, you can set the line-height of the span to match it:

```html
<div style="position: relative; background-color: gray; padding: 1%; width: 100%; height: 60px;">
  <div style="background-color: green; width: 50%; height: 100%">
    <span style="position: absolute; display: inline-block; text-align: center; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;line-height: 60px;">
      50%
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can `line-height` element inherit size of parent ? - Because I might not know the exact value of size

Comment: No, you would need to specify it.

Comment: That is really strange, I can't even use percentages. I guess this component can be designed different in order to make text align vertically in the middle.

Comment: Last question before I accept the answer, is there other way to design this component with same look and with text in the middle with using percentages?

Comment: This it! Love it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `line-height` to center your text vertically, in this case use `line-height: 60px`

```html
<div style="position: relative; background-color: gray; padding: 1%; width: 100%; height: 60px;">
  <div style="background-color: green; width: 50%; height: 100%">
    <span style="position: absolute; display: inline-block; text-align: center; width: 100%; line-height: 60px;">
      50%
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```